# Does changing magnetic field create different Electric field in EM waves?

Tags: electromagnetism, antennas

In em waves does changing magnetic field create different Electric field or it just help already created electric field by ac generator to propagate?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

One basic form of AC generator is itself basically a spinning magnet driven by some external force (flowing water, wind, a hamster on a hamster wheel, whatever). The magnet is placed near a coil of wire so that it induces an EMF in the wire.

It does this without there being any other AC generator in the system to produce the "original" electric field.

(Alternatively you can rotate the coil of wire in a stationary magnetic field.  But it amounts to the same thing. A magnetic field moving in relation to a wire generates an EMF. No other source of electric field is required to make this happen)

Comment: My question is how changing magnetic field helps electric field propagate?

Comment: @RaviBhat, the question you asked is "does changing magnetic field create different Electric field or it just help already created electric field ... to propagate". The answer is that it creates an electric field, it doesn't just enhance an existing one. ("helping an electric field to propagate" doesn't make any sense in established physics. Fields propagate according to Maxwell's equations. They don't need any help to do so)

Comment: Yes but according to Maxwell equation time changing magnetic field creates spatially varying electric field. I am unable to understand how can magnetic field make existing electric field spatially varying. My guess is it should create a new electric field. But then if creates new one how the em waves propagate.

Comment: @RaviBhat, The changing magnetic field doesn't affect any E field that was already present before the magnetic field was introduced. This is the principle of superposition. Nobody every claimed that it did. You asked if it did and I answered that it doesn't. So please just leave that (im)possibility aside.

Comment: As for EM waves, the changing magnetic field creates an electric field. But this electric field will itself be changing ... and therefore it will create a magnetic field...which will be changing...and so on. But nothing in the question you asked hinted that you were interested in EM waves. So if that's what you're really interested in you should open a new question and ask about them...but be explicit that that's what you're asking about.

Comment: Thanks updated the question.

Comment: OK but I already answered your original question. And your edits make my answer no longer fit. Moving the goal posts is a bit rude.